# Specifying that a task has multiple dependencies

Tags: ruby, build, rake

I would like to specify that:

- `:output_core` depends on `:build_core`
- `:build_extension` depends on `:build_core`
- `:output_extension` depends on both `:build_extension` and `:output_core`.

How would I specify that last one?  That in order to run the `:output_extensions` task, both `:build_extensions` and `:output_core` must be completed?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You specify them with an array:

```
task :output_extension => [:build_extension, :output_core]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This also works with Ruby 1.9 hash syntax: `task output_extension: [:build_extension]`